# Make the vim minted style use light terminal-like highlighting instead of dark

Tags: vim, minted

Whenever I'm highlighting code with the `minted` package, I use `\usemintedstyle{vim}`, which looks okay aside from the fact that it looks like a dark VIM color scheme applied onto a light background and it makes hard to read on a white background.

Is there any way to change the `vim` color scheme to match a light background?

[image: Code snippet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coloring is done by pygmentize, the command line interface to the Pygments library.  The vim style as defined in Pygments is really suited for a dark background, so the 'easy' solution is to  either specify a black background or to pick a pre-existing style that's suited for light backgrounds.

If you'd like to specify a new Pygments style, you can do so, but it's a bit complicated. Below I illustrate how to derive a new style ('myvim') from the vim style:

Step 1: Locate your pygments styles subdirectory -- on my machine that's in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygments/styles`

Step 2: In the pygments styles subdirectory create a new file, `myvim.py` that contains the following Python code:

```
from pygments.style import Style
from pygments.token import Keyword, Name, Comment, String, Error,          Number, Operator, Generic, Whitespace, Token

from vim import VimStyle

# inherit basic styles from the VimStyle class in vim.py
class MyVimStyle(VimStyle):
    # only change what we need by setting class attributes
    VimStyle.styles[Token] = "#000000"
    VimStyle.styles[Number] = "bold #cd00cd"
```

Step 3: Open the file `__init__.py` and add your new style to the `STYLE_MAP` dictionary:

```
#: Maps style names to 'submodule::classname'.
STYLE_MAP = {
        ... leave other styles definitions alone ...
    'myvim':    'myvim::MyVimStyle', # add this line at the end
}
```

Step 4: Compile `__init__.py` and `myvim.py` to bytcode

```
$ python __init__.py
$ python myvim.py
```

Step 5: Assuming you did everything correctly, you can test the built in styles plus your new style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

`manni' style on a white background:
\usemintedstyle{manni}
\begin{minted}{c}
char *test = "1000";
int *test_int = (int*) test;
printf("Machine is %s-endian", (test_int >> 1)? "big":"little");    
\end{minted}

`vim' style on a dark background:
\usemintedstyle{vim}
% note that minted seems to screw up the placment of the background here
\begin{minted}[bgcolor=black]{c}
char *test = "1000";
int *test_int = (int*) test;
printf("Machine is %s-endian", (test_int >> 1)? "big":"little");  
\end{minted}

Derived `myvim' style on a white background:
\usemintedstyle{myvim}
\begin{minted}{c}
char *test = "1000";
int *test_int = (int*) test;
printf("Machine is %s-endian", (test_int >> 1)? "big":"little");  
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

And here's what you should see:
[image: Minted new style example]

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why this isn't the default, since documents produced by latex are mostly white (well, articles at least).